# Create multiple histograms in a plot starting from bins and frequencies, instead than from samples?

Tags: r, performance, memory, ggplot2, histogram

I have a dataframe of size 10^6x3, i.e., 1 million samples for three variables. I would like to create three histograms in the same plot with overlay (alpha blending?) using R. The problem is that managing that many samples on my pc is possible (they fit in memory and R doesn't hang up forever), but not lightning fast. The code that generated the samples also gives me back lower and upper bin boundaries, and corresponding frequencies. Of course, this is much less data: I can choose the number of bins, but let's say 30 bins for variables, so 30x2x3=180 doubles. Is there a way in R to create overlayed histograms starting from bins and frequencies data? I would like to use `ggplot2`, but I'm open to solutions with base R or other packages. Also, what would you do in my situation? Would you use the original samples, and don't care about the longer computational time/memory occupation? Or would you go for bin/freqs? I'd like to use the raw data, but I'm worried that R could get too slow or hog too much memory, and that this could create issues in following computations. Thus a solution using raw data but optimized for speed/memory would be great, otherwise it's ok to use bin/freqs (if at all possible!).

Comment: What would be the benefit of computing the frequencies separately, if already have them?

Comment: Hi, Axeman! two reasons: 1. the code which generates the samples and computes the frequencies (let's call it Foo) has an awkward interface, so it's easier to experiment with number of bins, breaks, etc. in R than in Foo. 2. each time I rerun Foo, not only does it compute the frequencies, but it also regenerates the samples, which depend on complex computations. So If I want to change something about the histograms, it takes longer to do it in Foo than in R.

Comment: See this link for a way to increase binning speed: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/7457_8740a6a481f042ad8d2bce17e7b5bd04.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can! Using the bins and frequencies you can make a bar graph.

```
dat <- data.frame(group = rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 10),
                  bin = rep(1:10, 2),
                  frequency = rnorm(20, 5))
library(ggplot2)
```

Using alpha blending as you suggested:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = bin, y = frequency, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_identity(), alpha = 0.4)
```

[image: plot1]

Or we dodge the bars:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = bin, y = frequency, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I get the workings of the code, I'd really appreciate if you could give a short explanation. I just recently started using `ggplot2` and I'd like to start understanding what I do :)

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about "not lightning fast". The dataset below (1e6 cases X 3 variables) renders in ~6 sec on my machine (Core i7, Win7 x64). Is that too slow?

```
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(3e6, mean=rep(c(0,3,6), each=1e6)), ncol=3))
names(df) <- c("A","B","C")

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
gg.df <- melt(df, variable.name="category")

system.time({
  ggp <- ggplot(gg.df, aes(x=value, fill=category)) + 
    stat_bin(geom="bar", position="identity", alpha=0.7)
  plot(ggp)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    5.68    0.53    6.24
```

Comment: Interesting! But I've never used `reshape` so I don't really understand your code. I only get that your `df` has three columns - like mine. Would it be possible to make overlayed histograms using that `df`? In @Axeman answer two variables are stored one after the other in the first column of the `data.frame`, and R separates them based on the categorical `group` variable. With just an handful of variables this is not complicated, but I wonder if I could skip this "piling" step.

Comment: That is exactly what the `melt` step is doing. Go through his code step by step and see what is happening to the data. The binning is done here entirely by `ggplot` (`stat_bin` in this case).

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand @jlhoward answer too. It's a pity I cannot choose two answers :)

Comment: The other post answered your question; mine was more of a question than an answer. BTW `melt(...)` converts a data set from "wide" format (data in separate columns), to "long" format (all data in one column, with a second column indicating which column the original data came from). `ggplot` expects long format, so this pattern: df -> melt -> ggplot is extremely common.